# C++ Visual Studio 2013 Strange error but code runs

Tags: c++, templates, multidimensional-array, properties, declspec

I am trying to use __declspec properties and getting some strange errors when using multiple indicies. I get the error:
"expression must be a pointer to a complete object type" in visual studio, but the code seems to run fine. Here is the code I am using:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

template<typename T>
class testClass
{
public:
    __declspec (property (get = GetValue, put = PutValue))
        T test[][];

    T GetValue(int x, int y)
    {
        return _internalVal[x][y];
    }

    void PutValue(int x, int y, T lValue)
    {
        _internalVal[x][y] = lValue;
    }
private:
    T _internalVal[3][3];

};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    testClass<int> tc;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){

            tc.test[i][j] = i * j;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This example is using a __declspec property on a template class using a multidimensional property. If i remove one set of brackets and parameters, it seems the error goes away and the code runs as expected. As the code is now, it throws an error in visual studio and still runs.

Why is this a concern? I work in a team and the others will not be pleased if errors appear, and likely will assume the code wont work, although it will. Is there a way to suppress such errors? Why is this happening?

Comment: There's no error or warning with Visual C++ 2015 using /W4.

Comment: Are you sure that is not an Intellisense error? I mean a compile error would not produce an executable.

Comment: Compiler rrror codes are prepended with an error code like C0000. What code do you get?

Comment: It looks to be an intellisence error. I will try with c++ 2015 and see what I get as well. If upgrading to 2015 fixes the error, it may be worth doing. Is there any way to supress a single type of intellisence error?